# Linux App that monitors log and add rules to iptables

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall

I used to use a linux software that monitors logs like http, ssh, etc and if it detects that someone is trying to use brute force, it blocks that ip by adding a rule to iptables. I forgot what that software is called. It's opensource and free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fail2ban`](http://www.fail2ban.org/) does that, although I don't think it's the only such tool.  ([Amazed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5535/amazed) mentioned [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/), although it seems to be SSH specific.)

Comment: If that's the answer you needed, good etiquette here is to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: There's also denyhosts